# Cannot Install Ubuntu 20.10 normally, only is (safe graphics) mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I tried to install Ubuntu 20.10 normally using USB stick but once I choose the first setup option ***Ubuntu** I cannot continue to the next step, so I choose the second choice **Ubuntu (safe graphics)**.

[image]

After finishing the installation I cannot choose the first option from GRUB screen which is (**Ubuntu**) I used to choose the second one (**Advanced options for Ubuntu**) and the error below shown to me and I restarted the system many times so I can access Ubuntu with low graphics and low resolution.

```
[     0.298008] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
/dev/sdb5: Clean, 207672/6225920 files, 3573307/24882688 blocks
```

I have SSD as sda for Windows and HDD as sdb for data and I reserved 70G for Ubuntu, and UEFI system.

Also I select sdb as device for boot loader installation, so I kept every system on its disk to avoid booting problems.

**My PC specs:**
CPU Ryzen 5 1600AF
M.B. MSI b450 tomahawk max
RAM 16G
GPU AMD Rx 570 4G

Kindly advise me to sort this problem out!

Answer (score 1):

I had that issue recently, and it seems to happen very frequently with AMD hardware

Here are the steps :

- With the selector on your main GRUB entry type `e` to enter the editor
- Find the entry that starts with `linux`
- Delete `quiet splash` (or anything you have at the **end** of the line, but not touching any word that starts with a `$`) from the line (don't worry the change is only going to last one boot) replacing it with `nomodeset`
  (the line should look like this

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.9.12-050912-generic root=UUID=<REDACTED> ro nomodeset $vt_handoff
```

- Boot using `F10` and wait to be spawned to the DE (if you don't no worry, stike `Ctrl-Alt-F2` to enter the `tty`)
- Once logged and within an open terminal run :

```bsh
sudo -i
nano /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
```

Change the `COMPRESS` line from `COMPRESS=lz4` to `COMPRESS=gzip`

Save the changes (`Ctrl+x | y | Return`)

then run `update-initramfs -u`

Reboot and done

Comment: I tried this solution, after reboot from the first choice "Ubuntu" it takes a while with black screen then I hear an loud sound of the PC's fan and I should reboot the PC using the power button! Although I added the "nomodeset" as you mentiond above.       Thank you